# In-memory SQLite and database disappearing

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using Nancy to create an api to a database, and am wanting to test / develop against an in-memory database.

I am using an instance of my database class in a custom bootstrapper class with the connection string `Data Source=:memory:`, which in turn is creating the necessary tables - I have stepped through this and I'm confident this is occuring.

I am then obtaining a new connection using the same connection string to load/save data, but even a simple select is coming up with the sql error that the table doesn't exist.

Is there a fault in this logic of creating and using a new connection with the same connection string?

Comment: Did you ever work out a solution for this?  I'm having the same issue with my update tests.  I'll get an entity out, but when I try to update that entity, the connection will have closed after the first get.  Trying to think of a way to keep the connection open during the lifespan of the test!

Answer (score 2):

OK, so straight from the docs:

> The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed. "

However, this can be worked around with multiple connections by using `cache=shared` in your connection string.

However, this isn't a solution to the problem because as soon as the last connection closes, the database ceases to exist.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the `SQLiteConnection` open and ensure that the `DbContext` does **not** own the connection.  This way, when the `DbContext` is disposed by the container, the connection doesn't get closed with it.  Note: This only works with EF6.  You can still pass the flag in EF5, but the context will still close the connection when the context gets disposed.

I created a `TestBootstrapper` which inherited the working Bootstrapper from the web project.

As part of the `ConfigureRequestContainer` method, I used a method factory on the `DbContext` registration which created a new `DbContext` each time, but used the existing connection.  If you don't do this, the `DbContext` will get disposed after your first request and the second request will fail.

```
public class TestBootstrapper : Bootstrapper
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "data source=:memory:;cache=shared;";
    private static SQLiteConnection _connection;
    private static TestInitializer _initializer = new TestInitializer();

    protected override void ConfigureRequestContainer(TinyIoCContainer, NancyContext context) 
    {
        container.Register<Context>((_,__) => 
        {
            if (_connection == null)
                _connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);

            // The false flag tells the context it does not own the connection, i.e. it cannot close it. (EF6 behaviour only)
            var dbContext = new Context(_connection, _initializer, false);

            if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                _connection.Open();

            // I build the DB and seed it here
            _initializer.InitializeDatabase(context);

            return dbContext;
        });

        // Additional type registrations
    }

    // Call this method on a [TearDown]
    public static void Cleanup() 
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _connection.Close();
        _connection = null;
    }
}
```